# Convert Json array of list to array of json with key value pairs

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I am looking to convert json with array, to array of jsons with key value pairs.

Below is the format I have.
The index zero has three array of list with different values in it.
The values of index zero should be represented in one single array with different json for each list as key value pair as shown below.

Example

```
{'0': ['ID:123,qty:2,name:zbc',
      'ID:234,qty:3,name:xyz',
      'ID:456,qty:6,name:opq']}
```

to be converted to

```
[{"ID":"123","qty":"2","name":"zbc"},{"ID":"234","qty":"3","name":"xyz"}{"ID":"456","qty":"6","name":"opq"}]
```

The whole data looks like below

```
{'0': ['ID:123,qty:2,name:zbc',
      'ID:234,qty:3,name:xyz',
      'ID:456,qty:6,name:opq']
'1':['ID:666,qty:2,name:ppp',
    'ID:322,qty:5,name:uuu'],
'2' : ['ID:333,qty:3,name:pqr',
      'ID:444,qty:5,name:mmm',
     'ID:555,qty:6,name:iii']
 }
```

Convert to as below:

```
[{"ID":"123","qty":"2","name":"zbc"}, 
 {"ID":"234","qty":"3","name":"xyz"}, 
 {"ID":"456","qty":"6","name":"opq"}]
 
[{"ID":"666","qty":"2","name":"ppp"}, 
 {"ID":"322","qty":"5","name":"uuu"}]

[ {"ID":"333","qty":"3","name":"pqr"}, 
  {"ID":"444","qty":"5","name":"mmm"}, 
  {"ID":"555","qty":"6","name":"iii"}]
```

Please help here.

Comment: What do you mean by `['ID:123,qty:2,name:zbc', ['ID:234,qty:3,name:xyz', ['ID:456,qty:6,name:opq']` ? 3 opening brackets, but only 1 closing bracket? This isn't even valid Python syntax.

Comment: Neither is your expected output, which is also invalid `[{...}, {...} {...}] [{...} {...}] [{...} {...} {...}]`. What is this? List of lists? Or 3 different lists? Commas aren't event present to mark separation between elements.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question,there were few errors.  they are three different lists

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
data = {
    '0': [
        'ID:123,qty:2,name:zbc',
        'ID:234,qty:3,name:xyz',
        'ID:456,qty:6,name:opq'
    ],
    '1': [
        'ID:666,qty:2,name:ppp',
        'ID:322,qty:5,name:uuu'
    ],
    '2' : [
        'ID:333,qty:3,name:pqr',
        'ID:444,qty:5,name:mmm',
        'ID:555,qty:6,name:iii'
    ]
}
```

#### Solution 1:

Split each string by comma `,` to get each key-value pair and then by `:` to extract the key part and the value part.

```
data_list = []

for text_list in data.values():
    current_list = []
    for text in text_list:
        text_dict = {}
        for split in text.split(','):
            key, _, value = split.partition(':')
            text_dict[key] = value
        current_list.append(text_dict)
    data_list.append(current_list)

print(data_list)
```

#### Solution 2:

Use regex to transform each string into dictionary format. Then use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert it to `dict`.

```
import ast
import re

key_value_re = re.compile(r"(\w+):(\w+)")
data_list = [
    [
        ast.literal_eval("{" + key_value_re.sub(r'"\1":"\2"', text) + "}")
        for text in text_list
    ]
    for text_list in data.values()
]

print(data_list)
```

**Output (both solutions):**

```
[
    [
        {
            "ID": "123",
            "qty": "2",
            "name": "zbc"
        },
        {
            "ID": "234",
            "qty": "3",
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "ID": "456",
            "qty": "6",
            "name": "opq"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ID": "666",
            "qty": "2",
            "name": "ppp"
        },
        {
            "ID": "322",
            "qty": "5",
            "name": "uuu"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ID": "333",
            "qty": "3",
            "name": "pqr"
        },
        {
            "ID": "444",
            "qty": "5",
            "name": "mmm"
        },
        {
            "ID": "555",
            "qty": "6",
            "name": "iii"
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of list and dictionary comprehension in a oneliner:

```
data = {'0': ['ID:123,qty:2,name:zbc',
      'ID:234,qty:3,name:xyz',
      'ID:456,qty:6,name:opq'],
'1':['ID:666,qty:2,name:ppp',
    'ID:322,qty:5,name:uuu'],
'2' : ['ID:333,qty:3,name:pqr',
      'ID:444,qty:5,name:mmm',
     'ID:555,qty:6,name:iii']
 }

[[{x.split(':')[0]:x.split(':')[1] for x in i.split(',')} for i in item] for item in data.values()]
```

Output:

```
[[{'ID': '123', 'qty': '2', 'name': 'zbc'},
  {'ID': '234', 'qty': '3', 'name': 'xyz'},
  {'ID': '456', 'qty': '6', 'name': 'opq'}],
 [{'ID': '666', 'qty': '2', 'name': 'ppp'},
  {'ID': '322', 'qty': '5', 'name': 'uuu'}],
 [{'ID': '333', 'qty': '3', 'name': 'pqr'},
  {'ID': '444', 'qty': '5', 'name': 'mmm'},
  {'ID': '555', 'qty': '6', 'name': 'iii'}]]
```

Comment: The index is not fixed , it varies it could grow upto 100000

Comment: That shouldn't pose a problem (as long as there are no nested values) as this solution only accesses the key and value pairs within the list items by index.